# Dart - Why do I get this error when running dart2js? "No se esperaba \dart-sdk\bin\dart2js.snapshot en este momento."

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I've tried running dart2js both choosing "Run as JavaScript" from the context menu, and from Tools -> Generate JavaScript.

Both methods producing the same console output (an error):

```
Running dart2js...
No se esperaba \dart-sdk\bin\dart2js.snapshot en este momento.
```

Translated from Spanish would be:

```
Running dart2js...
Didn't expect \dart-sdk\bin\dart2js.snapshot at this moment.
```

I'm running Windows 7, 64 bits.

Dart Editor version 0.2.6_r15355

Dart SDK version 0.2.6.0_r15355

Note: I used to be able to run dart2js successfully, now I get that error.

**Update: I've tried it with a [nightly build](https://gsdview.appspot.com/dart-editor-archive-continuous/latest/) and it worked well.**

Comment: Try to click in the file that has your main method and run the "Generate JavaScript", does it happen again?

Comment: Yes, it happens again. The same error.

Comment: Can anyone else reproduce this?

Comment: Sorry about this! Just to double check, what happens when you try a nightly build? https://gsdview.appspot.com/dart-editor-archive-continuous/latest/

Comment: The nightly build worked! Nice.

Comment: Great! Note that a new version of the weekly build was pushed yesterday, so you can probably just auto-update your previous editor install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments above, try switching to a nightly build. Sorry for the bug. I assume it was a bug and that it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It took me crazy amount of time to find link to nightly builds.

For those who is looking for it it's here: https://gsdview.appspot.com/dart-archive/channels/dev/release/latest/sdk/

Comment: What has this to do with the question? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695627 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833008

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Nothing directly but this question comes up on first page of Google results when I search for "Dart nightly build" :) I had really hard time finding nightly builds.

Comment: Probably because they are not called `nightly` ;-)